# Enumerating and replacing all tokens in a string file in python

Tags: python

I have a question for you, dear python lovers.

I have a corpus file, as the following:

```
Ah , this is greasy .
I want to eat kimchee .
Is Chae Yoon &apos;s coordinator in here ?
Excuse me , aren &apos;t you Chae Yoon &apos;s coordinator ? Yes . Me ?
-Chae Yoon is done singing .
This lady right next to me ... everyone knows who she is right ?
```

I want to assign a specific number for each token, and replace it with the assigned number on the file.

What I mean by saying token is, basically each group of characters in the file separated by `' '`. So, for example, `?` is a token, also `Excuse` is a token as well.

I have a corpus file which involves more than 4 million lines, as above. Can you show me a fastest way to do I want?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might be overkill but you could write your own classifier:

```
# Python 3.x
class Classifier(dict):
    def __init__(self, args = None):
        '''args is an iterable of keys (only)'''
        self.n = 1
        super().__init__()
        if args:
            for thing in args:
                self[thing] = self.n
    def __setitem__(self, key, value = None):
##        print('setitem', key)
        if key not in self:
            super().__setitem__(key, self.n)
            self.n += 1
    def setdefault(self, key, default = None):
        increment = key not in self
        n = super().setdefault(key, self.n)
        self.n += int(increment)
##        print('setdefault', n)
        return n
    def update(self, other):
        for k, v in other:
            self.setdefault(k)
    def transpose(self):
        return {v:k for k, v in self.items()}
```

Usage:

```
c = Classifier()
with open('foo.txt') as infile, open('classified.txt', 'w+') as outfile:
    for line in infile:
        line = (str(c.setdefault(token)) for token in line.strip().split())
        outfile.write(' '.join(line))
        outfile.write('\n')
```

To reduce the number of writes you could accumulate lines in a list and use `writelines()` at some set length.

If you have enough memory, you could read the entire file in and split it then feed that to `Classifier`.

De-classify

```
z = c.transpose()
with open('classified.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        line = (z[int(n)] for n in line.strip().split())
        print(' '.join(line))
```

---

For Python 2.7 `super()` requires arguments - replace `super()` with `super(Classifier, self)`.

---

If you are going to be working mainly with *strings* for the token numbers, in the class you should convert `self.n` to a string when *saving* it then you won't have to convert back and forth between strings and ints in your *working* code.

---

You also may be able to use [`LabelEncoder`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html) from sklearn.

Comment: super().__init__()
TypeError: super() takes at least 1 argument (0 given)

Comment: @yusuf are you using Python 2.x or 3.x?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a specific dictionary already to change your values, you need to simply map the new values.

```
mapping = { '?':1, 'Excuse':2, ...}
for k, v in mapping.iteritems():
    my_string = my_string.replace(k, v)
```

If you want to create a brand new dictionary:

```
mapping = list(set(my_string.split(' ')))
mapping = dict[(i,x) for i,x in enumerate(mapping)]
for k, v in mapping.iteritems():
    my_string = my_string.replace(k, v)
```

Comment: Thank you. But are you sure that I don't give two different numbers to the occurrences of the same token?

Comment: mapping = dict[(i,x) for i, x in enumerate(mapping)]
                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Need parentheses around the square brackets.

Answer (score 1):

```
from collection import defaultdict
from itertools import count
with open(filename) as f:
    with open(output, 'w+') as out:
      c = count()
      d = defaultdict(c.__next__)
      for line in f:
        line = line.split()
        line = ' '.join([d[token] for token in line])
        out.write(line)
```

Using a `defaultdict`, we remember what tokens we've seen.  Every time we see a new token, we get the next number and assign it to that token. This writes output to a different file.

Comment: AttributeError: 'itertools.count' object has no attribute '__next__'

Comment: @yusuf did you include the underscores?  `__next__`

Comment: You can put the two with statements on the same line - ```with open(filename) as f, open(output, 'w+') as out```.

Comment: Are you targeting Python 2?  in that case, use no underscores: `c.next`

Answer (score 1):

```
split = "super string".split(' ')
map = []
result = ''
foreach word in split:
    if not map.__contains__(word):
        map[word] = len(map)
    result += ' ' + str(map[word]
```

this way avoid to do my_string = my_string.replace(k, v) that makes it slow

Comment: When you shadow a builtin (map) make sure you realize you did it.

Comment: map[word] = len(map)
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not unicode

Answer (score 0):

Try the following: it assigns a numeric number to each token then replaces tokens with corresponding number.

```
a = """Ah , this is greasy .
I want to eat kimchee .
Is Chae Yoon &apos;s coordinator in here ?
Excuse me , aren &apos;t you Chae Yoon &apos;s coordinator ? Yes . Me ?
-Chae Yoon is done singing .
This lady right next to me ... everyone knows who she is right ?""".split(" ")

key_map = dict({(j,str(m)) for m,j in enumerate(set(a))})
" ".join(map(lambda x:key_map[x], a))
```

i.e. first map each unique token to a number, then you can use the key_map to assign the numeric value to each token